# Post action in ASP.NET MVC always receives null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have read a lot of questions regarding similar issues, but none of them seems to work for me.

I am receiving `null` for the movie object in the post action method.

This is my controller:

```cs
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    [Route("movies/all")]
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult All()
    {
        List<string> movies = new List<string>();
        movies.Add("Some Movie");
        movies.Add("Diamond Team");

        //Get movies
        return Ok(movies);
    }

    [Route("movies/post")]
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] Movie movie)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(movie);
        List<string> movies = new List<string>();
        movies.Add(movie.title);

        //Get movies
        return Ok(movies);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the Movies class:

```cs
public class Movie
{  
    public string title { get; set; }
    public float rating { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }

    public Movie(string title,float rating, int year)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Movie()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the post request (using postman), I have tried either `application/json` and `application/json; charset=utf-8` as the Content-Type but in both cases I have received null for the movie object:

```json
{
    "title":"Some Movie",
    "rating":"1.87",
    "year":"2011"
}
```

Postman screenshots:
[image: Body]

[image: Headers]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I tested your code with Postman, no problems with the code, hence that narrows down the issue to usage of Postman. Do you put your request JSON into view named "Body" in Postman? BR

Comment: Yes, I put into body, and picked the "raw" option

Comment: OK, can you then add screen-shots to your question for the following request settings from Postman: Headers, Body

Comment: I added them to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change your request JSON to this:

```
{
    "title":"Some Movie",
    "rating":1.87,
    "year":2011
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model must first be serialized and then passed to data in ajax call. this is one sample, You have to change the model according to your needs....

```
$("#btnPost").click(function() {  
        var employee = new Object();  
        employee.Name = $('#txtName').val();  
        employee.Address = $('#txtDesignation').val();  
        employee.Location = $('#txtLocation').val();  
        if (employee != null) {  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/JQueryAjaxCall/AjaxPostCall",  
                data: JSON.stringify(employee),  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json",  
                success: function(response) {  
                    if (response != null) {  
                        alert("Name : " + response.Name + ", Designation : " + response.Designation + ", Location :" + response.Location);  
                    } else {  
                        alert("Something went wrong");  
                    }  
                },  
                failure: function(response) {  
                    alert(response.responseText);  
                },  
                error: function(response) {  
                    alert(response.responseText);  
                }  
            });  
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in the postman you can use different way to call method. Click on  code button and choose one of way to call method.

[image]

you  can use jquery and put code onto section....